# Php MysQl Search script returns blank page

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a simple page script to loop through a dynamic table that gets data from the database. But when I click on search the page returns blank with no error. I'm trying to understand what's going on without success.

**display_table.php**

```
<?php
  include('session.php');
if  ($_SESSION['login_user']){
   include 'includes/header.php';


   $searchQ = "SELECT * FROM companytable";


if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search_box']);
$searchQ .="WHERE title ='{$search_term}' ";
$searchQ .="OR country ='{$search_term}' ";
$searchQ .="OR description ='{$search_term}' ";
$searchQ .="OR timezone ='{$search_term}' ";
}
$query = mysqli_query($db, $searchQ) or die(mysqli_error());

}
```

**form**

```
<form class="form"  name="search_form" method="POST" action="display_table.php"> 
      <input id="search_box" style="padding: 2px;" class=""  type="text" name="search_box"> 
      <input  class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="search" value="&#128269;"> 
    </form>
```

**table**

```
<table>

  <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Time Zone</th>
  </tr>

  <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-th="ID"><?=$company['id'];?></a></td>
      <td data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Time Zone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
  </tr>

    <?php };?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
```

to reference the mysqli result you created, `$query`:

```
<?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
```

Comment: Same blank page return.

Comment: Have you confirmed the `$searchQ` you're creating has any rows in the result?

Comment: Well I made a test with    `$searchQ = "SELECT * FROM companytable LIMIT 5";` to see if the table would only return 5 rows at a time and it works. So I'm guessing yes.

Comment: Why not `echo $searchQ` after you build it and test that? If your `$_POST` is empty for example one would expect no results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object-oriented

```
<?php
  include('session.php');
if  ($_SESSION['login_user']){
   include 'includes/header.php';

   $query = "SELECT * FROM companytable ";

   if(isset($_POST['search_box'])){
    $search_term = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $query.=" WHERE title ='{$search_term}'
             OR country ='{$search_term}'
             OR description ='{$search_term}'
             OR timezone ='{$search_term}';";
   }

   if(!$s = $db->query($query)){
    die($db->error);
   }

}
```

**Table**

```
<table>

  <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Time Zone</th>
  </tr>

  <?php while($m = $s->fetch_object()){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-th="ID"><?=$m->id;?></a></td>
      <td data-th="Name"><?=$m->title;?></td>
      <td data-th="Description"><?=$m->description;?></td>
      <td data-th="Type"><?=$m->type;?></td>
      <td data-th="Address"><?=$m->address;?></td>
      <td data-th="Country"><?=$m->country;?></td>
      <td data-th="Time Zone"><?=$m->timezone;?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
    };
    $s->free();
  ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Now I get this Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @Skynet check now, i changed some variables. Which version of php and mysql are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.6 version.

Comment: @Skynet in php or mysql? or both?

Comment: @Skynet check now.. if(isset($_POST['search_box'])){

Comment: I swaped for your code and still getting same error. I use 5.6 both in Php and MysQl. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

So turn out I decided to go with [sortable.js](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) It not only takes care of search but also takes care of sorting the rows by clicking on headers. So if you are looking for a clean fix, that would be it.

**form**

```
  <form class="form"  name="search_form">  <input  id="search" style="" class="form-control"  type="text" name="search" placeholder="&#128269; Search...">
```

**table**

```
<table id="table" class="sortable" >

  <thead style="cursor:pointer;">
      <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Time Zone</th>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-th="ID" sorttable_customkey="2"><?=$company['id'];?></a></td>
      <td data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Time Zone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php };?>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot>


</table>
```

**Search script**

```
<script src="js/sorttable.js"></script> //load sortable.js

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $search_rows = $('#table tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $search_rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
    </script>
```